# NodeJS merges objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I'm working on NodeJS to create a way to send pictures to multiple displays at once, currently my code has these statements:

```
var $   = require('jQuery');
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log:false });
var fs  = require('fs');

var Server = {
    server_address : "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",  // The server address
    playing_now    : Object // The playlist that are being synced
};

var Client = {
    clients : Object
};

app.listen(1337);
console.log("App is running on port 1337...");

function handler(request, response) {
    var ip_address = null;

    try{ ip_address = request.header('x-forwarded-for'); }
    catch(error){ ip_address = request.connection.remoteAddress; }

    Client.clients[ip_address] = "X";

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(500);
            return response.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end(data);
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on("RequestPlaylist", function(json){
        Client.clients[json["Address"]] = json["PlayList"];    

        if(typeof Server.playing_now[json["PlayList"]] === 'undefined'){
            $.ajax({
                url      : "http://" + Server.server_address + "/buildPlayList.php",
                type     : "GET",
                dataType : "jsonp",
                method   : "GET",
                data     : {RemoteIP : json["Address"], Name : json["PlayList"]}
            }).done(function(playlistJSON){
                console.log("________________________________________");
                console.log("Done");
                console.log(Server.playing_now);
                Server.playing_now[playlistJSON["playName"]] = playlistJSON;
                console.log(Server.playing_now);
                console.log("________________________________________");
            })    
        }else{
            console.log("________________________________________");
            console.log("Redirect");
            console.log(Server.playing_now);
            console.log("________________________________________");
        }    
    });
});
```

When a new clients connects, I store it's IP address on Client.clients, and when I get the json containing the urls to the images, I store it on Server.playing_now.

The problem is, when I output Server.playing_now, it includes the contents of Client.clients:

```
Done
{ [Function: Object] 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX': 'Default Media' }
{ [Function: Object]
  'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX': 'Default Media',
  'Default Media':
   { '1':
      { json: [Object],
        duration: '5',
        name: 'Slideshow',
        type: 'Image',
        sync: '1',
        callback: 'jQuery17207063492417801172_1377555709748' },
     playName: 'Default Media' } }
```

If it try to fetch the data again, this is the result:

```
Redirect
{ [Function: Object]
  '105.102.15.234': 'Default Media',
  'Default Media':
   { '1':
      { json: [Object],
        duration: '5',
        name: 'Entrenamiento PL',
        type: 'Image',
        sync: '1',
        callback: 'jQuery17207063492417801172_1377555709748' },
     playName: 'Default Media' } }
```

Nowhere in my code do I merge these two objects, if I comment out the Client object, it does return only the contents of Server.playing_now.

Any idea what could be happening? Or is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialized Clients (and Server):

```
var Client = {
    clients : Object
};
```

You are setting to `Object` which is the same thing (and a bad idea).  You really want `new Object()` or just `{}`

Try changing the initialization code to something like:

```
var Server = {
    server_address : "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",  // The server address
    playing_now    : {} // The playlist that are being synced
};

var Client = {
    clients : {}
};
```

Comment: This did it, so when I set it to just Object, it inherits all the properties and methods I append to any other object I create based on the same initialization? I got some code to clean up then.... Thanks! You might just save a lot of hassle.

Comment: In this case "Object" is the constructor function for creating a new thing of type: Object and is global in scope.  So basically what you are doing is assigning properties to a global variable in different places in your code where you have referenced it.